# package object type members and inheritence don't work together

Tags: scala, types

The following code compiles perfectly in Scala 2.11:

```
trait A {
  type B
  def f(x: B): Unit
}

/*package*/ object C extends A {
  trait Z
  type B = Z
  def f(x: Z): Unit = {}
}

object D {
  val s: C.Z = ???
  C.f(s)
}
```

But when the `package` before `object C` is uncommented, the following error message is produced:

```
error: type mismatch;
 found   : s.type (with underlying type C.Z)
 required: A.this.B
    C.f(s)
        ^
```

So somehow, Scala doesn't seem to be able to figure out, that `C.B` is actually a type alias of `C.Z`.

More strangely, the code does compile when you first compile the file with scalac, first without package object, and then with the package object without deleting the class files; so there also seems to be a bug with incremental compilation.

Does any of this make sense or is this simply a bug in the scala compiler?

More generally, I know that the main difference between package object and object is that for package objects, the same name is also allowed as package name (and the object is mapped to a slightly different name in the compiled class files). What are other differences? This clearly seems to be one and there also appear to be differences in implicit resolution precedence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compiles in 2.12. There was a fix for aliases in package objects, but I don't have a link, possibly related.

```
$ scala
Welcome to Scala 2.12.1 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_111).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala> :pa -raw
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

trait A {
  type B
  def f(x: B): Unit
}
package object C extends A {
  trait Z
  type B = Z
  def f(x: Z): Unit = {}
}

object D {
  val s: C.Z = ???
  C.f(s)
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.


scala> :quit
```

Verifying:

```
$ scala211
Welcome to Scala 2.11.8 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_111).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala> :pa -raw
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

trait A {
  type B
  def f(x: B): Unit
}
package object C extends A {
  trait Z
  type B = Z
  def f(x: Z): Unit = {}
}

object D {
  val s: C.Z = ???
  C.f(s)
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

<pastie>:13: error: type mismatch;
 found   : D.s.type (with underlying type C.Z)
 required: A.this.B
  C.f(s)
      ^
There were compilation errors!

scala>
```